# Camera video RTSP with low FPS not played on VLC-android version 1.7.1 and later

Tags: android, git, vlc, libvlc

My scenario is

> playing video from camera (old-model) with low FPS (2fps) in my
>   Android app, with VLC-android 1.7.0 it's worked great, but from VLC-android 1.7.1 to latest
>   build it's just showed up the first frame and freeze. 
>   The same results when I use VLC nightly build with same settings(Disable hardware acceleration and set network-catching 3500ms) worked with 1.7.0 and did not with 1.7.1 to 1.7.5 version.

My environments setup are below:

Android devices: Samsung s5 (v5.1), Nexus 5 (v4.4).

The Code for VLC options:

```
vlcOptions.add("--aout=opensles");
vlcOptions.add("--audio-time-stretch"); // time stretching
vlcOptions.add("--network-caching=3500");
vlcOptions.add("-vvv"); // verbosity
...
Media m = new Media(mLibVLC, Uri.parse(media));
m.setHWDecoderEnabled(false, false);   // Disable hardware acceleration
```

The same setting with nightly build: Disable hardware acceleration and network-catching 3500ms.

Did anybody face with this issue? or have experience on this issue?

Comment: I get the same problem with vlc player on ubuntu desktop. If framerate is lower than 15FPS, VLC can't seem to get the packets. Have you found any solution to your problem?

Comment: @MertCanErgün, still not but you can go to this link that I posted in VLC forum https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=130817 for what I tried.